# Switch from dvorak to qwerty when modifier key is pressed

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, dvorak, qwerty

Since I spend most of my day at a computer, I've become interested in learning to type on Dvorak. However, there's one thing holding me back: shortcuts. Shortcuts are designed to work on QWERTY, and there's a good deal of muscle memory there I am loathe to give up. Take CTRL-S for instance, normally I can do that with my left hand while my right is on the mouse, but with Dvorak S is on the right side of the board.

So here is my question: can I do something(write a script, download some software, whatever) that will automatically switch to qwerty when control, alt, or shift is pressed and then switch back when it's released? Any help is appreciated!